# Powershell Invoke-Command with-FilePath Gives ItemNotFoundException

Tags: powershell, remoting

I establish a persistent session then attempt to execute a script remotely using the following line:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session  -FilePath "FullStopBizTalkApp.ps1"  -argumentlist $BizTalkMgmtDBConString, $ApplicationNameInBizTalk
```

If I then execute: $_.Exception.ToString() I can see the following error:

```
System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\tfs_service\FullStopBizTalkApp.ps1' because it does not exist.
```

I am able to invoke commands from the same client to the same target server when using -ScriptBlock, I only get the problem when using -FilePath

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the path and file name of the script, or make sure your session working directory is the parent directory of the script file.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this too long!

The error was relating to the local path of the file before it was copied to target server. I fixed this by changing the value for the -FilePath argument