# Pass Argument to -FilePath in Powershell

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

It seem like everyone who answers this question skirts the issue by giving example that either A. Aren't relevant; or, B. Use the `-scriptBlock` version.

Here is what I want: I want to run a PowerShell script from my local machine, on a remote machine. I need to pass in an argument or parameter.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
$responseObject = Invoke-Command -ComputerName MININT-OU9K10R -FilePath C:\Users\Documents\RemoteProofOfConcept\validatePath.ps1 -ArgumentList $filename  -AsJob
```

I want to pass `$filename` into the `validatePath.ps1` script, and I can't figure out how to do this.

Can someone please show me how to do this, or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

None of these links have helped:

[Get script directory in PowerShell when script is invoked with Invoke-Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219461/get-script-directory-in-powershell-when-script-is-invoked-with-invoke-command)

[Powershell Invoke-Command with-FilePath Gives ItemNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478828/powershell-invoke-command-with-filepath-gives-itemnotfoundexception)

[How do I pass named parameters with Invoke-Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225748/how-do-i-pass-named-parameters-with-invoke-command)

Comment: No, that is the point. That file is on my local machine. If it were on the remote machine, I realize I could use the `-scriptblock`, but that isn't the case. I want to run local scripts on remote machines, and be able to pass in parameters to those scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on PowerShell v3. Are you on V2?

```
9# gc .\foo.ps1
param($myarg)

hostname
"parameter value of myarg is $myarg"
10# $filename = "c:\foo.txt"
11# Invoke-Command Beagle2 -FilePath .\foo.ps1 -ArgumentList $filename
BEAGLE2
parameter value of myarg is c:\foo.txt
```

BTW, foo.ps1 doesn't exist on the remote computer.  It is being transported by PowerShell to the remote computer for execution.  Now if `$filename` contains a local computer path, I'm not sure how that would work on the remote computer unless it points to a file that is common to both computers.